# How do i upload dataset in pycharm which i already have in my pc

Tags: python, pycharm, dataset

I tried adding datasets by making directory and categories, but it didn't worked out for me. it showed this. Please help.

```py
for category in CATEGORIES: 
    path = os.path.listdir() 
    for img in os.listdir(path): 
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray') 
        plt.show() 

ERROR : File "D:/DataScienceProj/main.py", line 12, in <module> path = os.path.listdir() AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'listdir' –
```

Comment: Please, instead of posting an image copy the code in the question. 
Also you don't add datasets in pycharm you may read them with python but it has nothing to do with uploading to pycharm.
Not sure of your intention for the code you have written. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Alright, sorry I'm just new to this place so really don't know rules and stuff. I'll do all of it right away. about the question what i meant is that for mnist datasets which are available online it is easy to load them etc etc. what i wanna know is if suppose i downloaded some datasets and have them in some folder of my pc.( they are jpg i.e images ) and i wanna know how can i load them in pycharm so that i can train it and test.

Comment: for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.listdir()
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join (path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow  (   img_array ,  cmap='gray')      
        plt.show() 
    break
    break
    
ERROR :  File "D:/DataScienceProj/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    path = os.path.listdir()
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'listdir'

Comment: Given the code you provide there is no evidence of what values has CATEGORIES

Comment: I had given the values of CATEGORIES as well sir. but i was not able to edit it here. :)